calculating multi dimensional gaussian distribution by nump apply_along_axis
I want to calculate multi dimensional Gaussian for multi-band image. For this purpose I need to consider each pixel with its value in different bands as vector to apply Gaussian which contains matrix multiplication of V^T*inv(covariance)*V.
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as lg
X,Y=np.meshgrid(np.arange(-10,11,1/10),np.arange(-10,11,1/10),indexing='xy')
Z=np.stack((X,Y))
cov=np.array([[10,-0.4],[-0.4,1]])
W=lg.inv(cov)
def ee(x):
    global W
    x=x.reshape((-1,1))
    
    return lg.matmul(lg.matmul(x.transpose(),W),x)[0,0]
tt=np.apply_along_axis(ee,0,Z)
p=np.exp(-0.5*tt)/(np.power(2*np.pi,cov.shape[0]/2)*np.power(lg.det(cov),0.5))
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(p)


enter image description here
I have found apply_along_axis as solution but my image size is (3,1000,1000) and apply_along_axis is so slow to apply function on pixels to find each pixel's probability. How can i speed it up fore real world applications.thank you

Check the edit of the solution

apply_along_axis just iterates on all axes except the designated one - i.e caling your function many timrs with 1d arrays. matmul/@ does a 'dot' on the last 2d of the argument arrays, and works in 'batch' mode on the leading dimension(s).  So it pays to leverage that power as much as possible.

Instead of looping along the axis, You could use the following:
a = Z.reshape(2,-1)
t = (W @ a * a).sum(0).reshape(*X.shape)

Check whether it produces the desired results:
np.allclose(tt, t)
True


yes it worked. thank you very much
